Is the forced detention of adult students by private universities legal?
It appears that there are certain private colleges in India which have rather stringent residential rules in their college campuses/dormitories. Specifically, the students are not allowed to physically leave the campus at any time during the entire semester and not allowed to physically leave their dormitories at night.
The only exception is when they obtain a letter from their parents, and get their leave approved by the college. Note that these students are generally adults (i.e, 18+ in India).
It seems to me that forcing citizens to be in a physical location is tantamount to kidnapping them. Since the students are adults, I do not see why their parents should have any say in this matter.

Is such an arrangement legal in India? I am also generally curious if this would be legal in other countries.
I suppose there could be an agreement between the university authority and the students which was made prior to them joining their program stating that the continued enrolment and the receipt of the degree is contingent on such living conditions. In which case, my question is: Is such an agreement legal?

This is very different from appearing in an exam, where the condition is "you must not leave the location for a few hours". Here the condition is "you must not leave the location for a few months at a time".
Clarification on how they are actually detained: The college has gates which are typically closed and guarded by security guards. If you wish to walk out, they would stop you. Whether someone has gotten into a violent situation with a guard is not something I know. The dormitories are blocked using turnstile gates which can check electronic and/or biometric identification and deny passage.

Are they actually physically detained, or are they just told their contract will be cancelled if they leave without permission? What would happen if one walked out the door? Would there be a violent struggle with guards or is it just some paper-pusher making a note?

Do the students know about this policy when they enroll in the school?

In the U.S. colleges and universities used to have "in loco parentis" power over their students, but this basically ended when the age of majority was reduced from 21 years to 18 years, largely in response to the Vietnam War.

@Barmar yes they do

@MichaelHall some agreements can still be illegal. Note that the students may also have relatively little bargaining power in negotiating the terms of the contract

@Lag the example I have in mind is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vellore_Institute_of_Technology and by forced, I mean that if they wish to leave the campus, they would have to go through a gate with guards

OK, well there isn't enough detail in the question to make a determination about the legality of the security measures the students and their parents have agreed to.

As a note about exams: There is generally nothing preventing you from walking out (blocking doors and such would be against fire safety violations). You will very likely face academic repercussions, but you are not detained in place.

When I was a student at Cambridge (England) in the 1970s, there were strict rules about when you were expected to be in college and how you had to get permission to be absent. Of course you could leave at any time without permission - but not if you expected to be allowed back in.

@MichaelKay similar rules still apply! https://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/univ/so/2019/chapter02-section12.html

canada
If this is accomplished by "coercive restraints" such that a person could not leave according to their own inclination and desire, then this would be the tort of false imprisonment and the criminal offence of unlawful confinement.
Even if there were a valid contract (and this will depend on assessment of illegality and voidness for public policy), one is always free to breach a contract and suffer any remedy in breach instead of following through with an obligation. If departing the premises is a breach of a valid contract, there are separate remedies for that and it would not excuse or justify imprisonment or confinement.

Providing there is no physical impediment, this is fine
Agreeing in a contract to do or not to do something is fine. If you then break that contract, you can open yourself up to consequences for breach of contract.
So, providing the students can physically leave if they want to, and are only restrained from doing so by fear of the consequences of breaking the contract they voluntarily entered, there's no problem.
Indeed, they could also be locked in (subject to any laws about fire escapes) providing that they would be released on request.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
